# How to parse the string content of debugDescription in XCUITest swift

Tags: swift, xctest, xcuitest, swift5.7, xcuielement

As debugDescription returns the XCUIElement UI Tree and this if of type String.
Want to fetch specific information based upon parameters like label :[String] will return all the label values, find_Application - will return the bundleID etc

Comment: What have you tried? I'd suggest not attempting to parse that output and use the tools that are given to you via XCUITest. Think: arrays, looping on those arrays, building another array?

Comment: Hi @MikeCollins the issue is I want to be independent of the synchronization issues that are encountered while performing actions on XCUIElement via XCUIElement query . I tried various possible ways to interact like using predicates or descendants(matching: .any) etc. I want to store all the UI information displayed on screen (captured via debuDescription). Parse through it and get the required line items like labels, title etc

Comment: It sounds like your mind is made up on your method. You're going to have to write your own parser; this does not exist. When faced with similar I often ask myself "Why has no-one attempted to do this before?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.snapshot().dictionaryRepresentation` which gives a parsed version of output of `element.debugDescription` or `element.snapshotDescription`.

You can use `element.snapshot().children` to get the child element's snapshots iteratively if you want to create your own parser.